# why isn't my route taking me to where I want to go in Flask with the correct parameter?

Tags: python, html, flask

So on my route displayinfo I am displaying information, so I made the request method GET, and additionally on my html page I have a form that asks for a user review, so I made the request method post. but, when I click the button to submit the form information it takes me to displayinfo/, but I want it to take me to displayinfo/(isbn number)

this is my python code

```js
@app.route("/displayinfo/<book_isbn>", methods=["POST", "GET"])

def displayinfo(book_isbn):
    #global Book_isbn
    #Book_isbn = book_isbn
    if request.method == "POST":

        if not session.get("USERNAME") is None:
            username = session.get("USERNAME")

            review = request.form.get("review")

            user_id = db.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=:username", {"username": username}).fetchone()
            book_id = db.execute("SELECT book_id FROM books WHERE isbn=:isbn)", {"isbn": book_isbn}).fetchone()

            db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (comment, user_id, book_id) VALUES (:comment, :user_id, :book_id)",{"comment": review, "user_id": user_id, "book_id":book_id})


            db.commit()

        else:
            return render_template("error.html", printthis="Not signed in.")

    else:

        if not session.get("USERNAME") is None:

            booktitle = db.execute("SELECT title FROM BOOKS WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": book_isbn}).fetchone()
            bookauthor = db.execute("SELECT author FROM BOOKS WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": book_isbn}).fetchone()
            bookyear = db.execute("SELECT year FROM BOOKS WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": book_isbn}).fetchone()
            bookisbn = db.execute("SELECT isbn FROM BOOKS WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": book_isbn}).fetchone()

            #res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": KqqGbJlg2XMOyLiYRAnhvQ, "isbns": bookisbn})

            return render_template("displayinfo.html", printtitle=booktitle, printauthor=bookauthor,printyear=bookyear, printisbn=bookisbn, book=booktitle)

            db.commit()
        else:
            return render_template("error.html", printthis="Not signed in.")
```

and this is my html code

```html
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block title %}Bookstore{% endblock %}

{% block head %}{{ printtitle }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{{ printtitle }}
{{ printauthor }}
{{ printyear }}
{{ printisbn }}





<p>Write a review: </p>

<form action="{{ url_for('displayinfo',  book_isbn=book.isbn)}}" method="post">

<!--, book_isbn=book.isbn-->

    <li><input type="text" name="review" placeholder="Write a review for {{ book }}"></li>
    <div class="btn">
    <button>Submit</button>
    </div>


</form>




{% block text %}{{ review }}{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

After

```py
db.commit()
```

Paste the line below

```py
return redirect(url_for('displayinfo', book_isbn=book_isbn))
```

The relevant imports are:

```py
from flask import redirect, url_for
```

Comment: that still gives me a "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." error. because when I click submit on the form it takes me to display/ when I want it to take me to display/(some numbers)

Comment: @aarushi777 Please update your post with the latest code that includes my suggestions.

Comment: @aarushi777 On a related note, the parameter you're passing to the render template involves passing the `booktitle` as the `book` and in your template, you're calling `book_isbn=book.isbn` That seems incorrect. You probably want `<form action="{{ url_for('displayinfo',  book_isbn=printisbn)}}" method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

The book variable passed to the template from Flask doesn't seem to be a book object but rather a string with it's content as the book title.

```
return render_template("displayinfo.html", printtitle=booktitle, printauthor=bookauthor,printyear=bookyear, printisbn=bookisbn, book=booktitle)
```

Perhaps you could try fixing it by passing a book object or replacing `book.isbn` with the isbn string you are passing - `bookisbn`

On another note, I suggest using a trailing slask at the end of the URL in @app.route. It's better, according to the Flask Quickstart - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behaviorhttps://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior

Comment: Thanks, but how do I pass a book object in my HTML code without using javascript?

Comment: When you return using Flask's render_template function, you can pass template variables to the HTML page. You are already passing strings - in the same method, you can pass a python object and access it as a normal object. Since you currently don't have a book object as you have the data stored in strings, I suppose it's not required. It's not in anyway different than how you implemented passing strings! If you need an example to look at, just see how the user object is passed in this tutorial - https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates